# What is wrong with this javascript regex string.replace?

Tags: node.js, replace, aws-lambda

**UPDATE**: I've discovered this problem is because of the "stringified" output which contains no spaces or newlines and is different than the original JSON.

Stringified output:

```
{"eventType":"Delivery","mail":{"timestamp":"2021-08-09T20:41:51.515Z","source":"removed@email.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:1234567890:identity/removed.com","sendingAccountId":"1234567890","messageId":"1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b","destination":["removedl@email.com"],"headersTruncated":false,"headers":[{"name":"From","value":"removed@email.com"},{"name":"To","value":"removed@email.com"},{"name":"Subject","value":"Test"},{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"},{"name":"Content-Transfer-Encoding","value":"7bit"}],"commonHeaders":{"from":["removed@email.com"],"to":["removed@email.com"],"messageId":"1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b","subject":"Test"},"tags":{"ses:operation":["SendEmail"],"ses:configuration-set":["GenericLog"],"ses:source-ip":["123.123.123.123"],"ses:from-domain":["email.com"],"ses:caller-identity":["user1"],"ses:outgoing-ip":["234.234.234.234"]}},"delivery":{"timestamp":"2021-08-09T20:41:52.880Z","processingTimeMillis":1365,"recipients":["removed@email.com"],"smtpResponse":"250 2.6.0 <1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b@email.amazonses.com> [InternalId=11231247472, Hostname=CO6PR12MB5396.namprd12.prod.outlook.com] 12090 bytes in 0.214, 55.135 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery","reportingMTA":"a48-108.smtp-out.amazonses.com"}}
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I want to remove the `:` from the key names and replace it with a `_` in the following JSON. (In the `tags` section)

```
{
    "eventType": "Delivery",
    "mail": {
        "timestamp": "2021-08-09T20:41:51.515Z",
        "source": "removed@email.com",
        "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:1234567890:identity/removed.com",
        "sendingAccountId": "1234567890",
        "messageId": "1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b",
        "destination": [
            "removedl@email.com"
        ],
        "headersTruncated": false,
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "From",
                "value": "removed@email.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "To",
                "value": "removed@email.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Subject",
                "value": "Test"
            },
            {
                "name": "MIME-Version",
                "value": "1.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                "value": "7bit"
            }
        ],
        "commonHeaders": {
            "from": [
                "removed@email.com"
            ],
            "to": [
                "removed@email.com"
            ],
            "messageId": "1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b",
            "subject": "Test"
        },
        "tags": {
            "ses:operation": [
                "SendEmail"
            ],
            "ses:configuration-set": [
                "GenericLog"
            ],
            "ses:source-ip": [
                "123.123.123.123"
            ],
            "ses:from-domain": [
                "email.com"
            ],
            "ses:caller-identity": [
                "user1"
            ],
            "ses:outgoing-ip": [
                "234.234.234.234"
            ]
        }
    },
    "delivery": {
        "timestamp": "2021-08-09T20:41:52.880Z",
        "processingTimeMillis": 1365,
        "recipients": [
            "removed@email.com"
        ],
        "smtpResponse": "250 2.6.0 <1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b@email.amazonses.com> [InternalId=11231247472, Hostname=CO6PR12MB5396.namprd12.prod.outlook.com] 12090 bytes in 0.214, 55.135 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery",
        "reportingMTA": "a48-108.smtp-out.amazonses.com"
    }
}
```

I've created a node.js Lambda function that is being called by AWS Kinesis. It processes the above JSON and the following code is being used. I am debugging, so I am simply trying to search and replace the string for testing:

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = async (payload, context) => {

        payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
        payload = payload.replace(/".*:.*":/g, 'replaced');
        
        console.log('Replaced payload:', payload);
};
```

I've run the regex through multiple code testing sites and it correctly identifies all 6 occurrences of the key names with a `:` in them. I've even used [this](https://www.venea.net/web/js_regexp_online_tester) tester, and it correctly replaces all 6 strings as expected. But, when it runs on Lambda I get the following output:

```
Replaced payload: {replaced"a48-108.smtp-out.amazonses.com"}}
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this some weird thing happening in Lambda?

Note, if I simply output the unmodified `payload` variable it matches the input JSON, so that is not the issue.

I've got additional code which should complete this task successfully once I solve this mystery. But, if you could provide the code to replace `:` with `_` in the key names, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind that simply using `.*` means "as many characters as you can match", i.e. it's eager. You can add a `?` for lazy matching, as in "match as few as possible".

I suggest using `/".*?:.*?":/g` since this basically means "get all characters to the closest `:` and then the characters to the closest `":`".

---

Using a recursive function to map the object instead of using a RegExp on the JSON version:

```js
const data = { "eventType": "Delivery", "mail": { "timestamp": "2021-08-09T20:41:51.515Z", "source": "removed@email.com", "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:1234567890:identity/removed.com", "sendingAccountId": "1234567890", "messageId": "1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b", "destination": ["removedl@email.com"], "headersTruncated": false, "headers": [{ "name": "From", "value": "removed@email.com" }, { "name": "To", "value": "removed@email.com" }, { "name": "Subject", "value": "Test" }, { "name": "MIME-Version", "value": "1.0" }, { "name": "Content-Type", "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" }, { "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "value": "7bit" }], "commonHeaders": { "from": ["removed@email.com"], "to": ["removed@email.com"], "messageId": "1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b", "subject": "Test" }, "tags": { "ses:operation": ["SendEmail"], "ses:configuration-set": ["GenericLog"], "ses:source-ip": ["123.123.123.123"], "ses:from-domain": ["email.com"], "ses:caller-identity": ["user1"], "ses:outgoing-ip": ["234.234.234.234"] } }, "delivery": { "timestamp": "2021-08-09T20:41:52.880Z", "processingTimeMillis": 1365, "recipients": ["removed@email.com"], "smtpResponse": "250 2.6.0 <1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b@email.amazonses.com> [InternalId=11231247472, Hostname=CO6PR12MB5396.namprd12.prod.outlook.com] 12090 bytes in 0.214, 55.135 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery", "reportingMTA": "a48-108.smtp-out.amazonses.com" } };

function convert(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.map(convert);
    const result = {};
    for(const key in obj) {
        result[key.replace(/:/g, '_')] = convert(obj[key]);
    }
    return result;
}

const converted = convert(data);
console.log(converted);
console.log(JSON.stringify(converted, null, 4));
```

Comment: Sounds like we're on to something. But, still problems. With the new regex the beginning output looks like this: `{replaced{replacedreplacedreplaced[replaced[{replacedreplacedreplacedreplacedreplacedreplacedreplaced`

Comment: Hmm. If you just want to target keys, `"[^"]*":` should work, as long as your keys don't have double quotes in them. Alternatively, create a recursive function to map your objects with altered keys.

Comment: yeah. I think the most reliable solution is to use the recursive function. I understand the concept but still trying to figure out how to manipulate a JSON object. Care to give me a code example? Thanks!

Comment: @Appleoddity I've updated my answer with a function that works on a regular object instead of a JSON string.

Comment: Yes. That works perfectly. I'm a little unclear on what some of the syntax does (my lack of javascript knowledge), so I'll keep deciphering it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Basically the function immediately returns non-objects, such as strings. Arrays (which are also objects) are mapped, e.g. every element replaced with `convert(element)` using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Then for actual (non-Array) objects, I create a new object, then copy over the values. But instead of using the original key, I replace every `:` in the key with `_`, and instead of using the original value I use `convert(value)` instead, thus recursively applying the `convert` function.

Comment: This is needed when there are multiple matches per line. My test data contained newlines and it worked without `?` but once the new lines / pretty format is gone `?` is needed to stop at the first match.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on your update comment:

> **UPDATE**: I've discovered this problem is because of the "stringified" output which contains no spaces or newlines and is different than the original JSON.

You can add the following options to `JSON.stringify` to properly format the stringified output.

```js
JSON.stringify(payload, null, 4);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let payload = {"eventType":"Delivery","mail":{"timestamp":"2021-08-09T20:41:51.515Z","source":"removed@email.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:1234567890:identity/removed.com","sendingAccountId":"1234567890","messageId":"1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b","destination":["removedl@email.com"],"headersTruncated":false,"headers":[{"name":"From","value":"removed@email.com"},{"name":"To","value":"removed@email.com"},{"name":"Subject","value":"Test"},{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"},{"name":"Content-Transfer-Encoding","value":"7bit"}],"commonHeaders":{"from":["removed@email.com"],"to":["removed@email.com"],"messageId":"1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b","subject":"Test"},"tags":{"ses:operation":["SendEmail"],"ses:configuration-set":["GenericLog"],"ses:source-ip":["123.123.123.123"],"ses:from-domain":["email.com"],"ses:caller-identity":["user1"],"ses:outgoing-ip":["234.234.234.234"]}},"delivery":{"timestamp":"2021-08-09T20:41:52.880Z","processingTimeMillis":1365,"recipients":["removed@email.com"],"smtpResponse":"250 2.6.0 <1123bfe-123123b12e12d2c212a-123b12c2e1123-213f312d32c123b@email.amazonses.com> [InternalId=11231247472, Hostname=CO6PR12MB5396.namprd12.prod.outlook.com] 12090 bytes in 0.214, 55.135 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery","reportingMTA":"a48-108.smtp-out.amazonses.com"}};

payload = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 4)
payload = payload.replace(/".*:.*":/g, 'replaced');

console.log('Replaced payload:', payload);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's solving the problem. Should I be worried about my use of regex in this way?

Comment: @Appleoddity I don't think there's anything wrong with using regex in that way, but an accidental match could break your code.